# Desplegar video de forma privada en aplicación web MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc, seguridad, video

En una aplicación web **MVC5** necesito comenzar a desplegar contenido de video del cliente, sin embargo, el requerimiento es que estos videos no puedan ser vistos en otra plataforma, dicho de otra forma, que el video no pueda ser visto o descargado a través de la URL que muestre el navegador al inspeccionar la página.

He estado evaluando la posibilidad de subir el contenido a **vimeo**, al parecer ellos ofrecen un paquete donde puedes definir a través de que dominios puede ser visto el contenido.

Necesito de su experiencia publicando material privado en formato de video. ¿Que herramienta puedo utilizar?

Comment: Has probado con un servicio rest con webapi? también con una conexión tcpclient? o wcf?

Comment: ¿Debes subir el video a un tercero o lo puedes almacenar en tu servidor?

Comment: El cielo es el límite. Preferiría no ser yo el que administre la infraestructura, por lo que preferiría hacerlo mediante un tercero